# Tracking HTTP requests and responses

Tags: c#, http

Is it possible to get all HTTP requests of a browser?

For example: we have opened the browser, navigated to google.com, searched for a string, clicked on any link and I got some error.
Now I want to track all HTTP requests from opening browser.
We have been using 'fiddler' to do so. But we want to use C# code to track all HTTP requests as well as HTTP responses. And we want to use the failed HTTP responses in our program.

Any information on this will be very helpful.

Answer (score 7):

You could use [SharpPcap](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/sharppcap.aspx) to implement your own 'sniffer', or use a [`HttpListener`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx) to create a proxy that forwards web requests.

Comment: Thankyou. Can U give an eg...?

Comment: No, sorry, I can't create a network sniffer or http proxy in an answer. It isn't easily done, and I've never done it before in C#. You could read the links I've provided and try if you can create one yourself.

Comment: Ok. I tried SharpPcap for that but I havent gained any thing. And HttpListner is a new one for me. Let me try with this one.                                                                 Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

AFAICS, there is no way of implementing this which does not replicate what you are already doing with fiddler (albeit that you could implement a passive sniffer rather than a proxy).